# Long chapter name second line indent in the TOC

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I'm LaTeX newbe and trying to make a document with some requirements.
Searching for similiar issues here and through whole internet gave me no result.
The point is to remove the long chapter name second (third, fourth...) line indent within the TOC.

[What I do have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZk47.png)

[What I want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGdDW.png)

[Detailed explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/556LF.png)

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}    
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\newcommand{\acronymsname}{This is a long, really long name for acronyms list to show how it looks within the Table of Contents}
\newcommand{\introductionname}{Introduction}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{\acronymsname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\acronymsname}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\(E\)] --- E-letter
\item[\(j\)] --- j-letter
\item[\(k\)] --- k-letter
\end{itemize}
\chapter*{\introductionname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\introductionname}
Introduction text.
\chapter{First Chapter}
First Chapter text.
\section{Section One in the 1st Chapter}
...Some text...
\subsection{Subsection N1 within 1.1}
...New text...
\subsection{Subsection N2 within 1.1}
...Other text...        
\section{Section Two in the 1st Chapter}
...More text...
\chapter{Second Chapter --- This Chapter Name is Really Long Too as Well as Acronyms List so it May Take at Least Two Strings}
Second Chapter text.
\section{Section One in the 2nd Chapter}
...Some text...
\section{Section Two in the 2nd Chapter}
...More text...
\end{document}
```

I assume the "tocloft" package may help me. Or not....?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476177/36296

Comment: This solution:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476177/36296
works well.
But I want to leave the 2nd line indent of numbered chapters intact. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two different solutions are posted
[Here - First](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634226/long-chapter-name-second-and-further-lines-indent-in-the-table-of-contents/634475#634475)
and
[Here - Second](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=34737)
.
Both of them are working and qualitative.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty hack:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}    
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\newcommand{\acronymsname}{This is a long, really long name for acronyms list to show how it looks within the Table of Contents}
\newcommand{\introductionname}{Introduction}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{\acronymsname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-21.855pt}{\acronymsname}}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\(E\)] --- E-letter
\item[\(j\)] --- j-letter
\item[\(k\)] --- k-letter
\end{itemize}
\chapter*{\introductionname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\introductionname}
Introduction text.
\chapter{First Chapter}
First Chapter text.
\section{Section One in the 1st Chapter}
...Some text...
\subsection{Subsection N1 within 1.1}
...New text...
\subsection{Subsection N2 within 1.1}
...Other text...        
\section{Section Two in the 1st Chapter}
...More text...
\chapter{Second Chapter --- This Chapter Name is Really Long Too as Well as Acronyms List so it May Take at Least Two Strings}
Second Chapter text.
\section{Section One in the 2nd Chapter}
...Some text...
\section{Section Two in the 2nd Chapter}
...More text...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz,
Thank you very much for your quick answers and effort!
I've noticed your last edition (adding the "[p]" option to make the page number bottom alignment).
This trick is very nice for temporary use. And yes, it's really dirty :)
But in my case, there are some more issues.

Comment: In the main document (not MWE) TOC I use dots for chapters as well as for sections:
"\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}".
So when this hack is implemented (chapter name is placed within smth like "frame"), dots are only visible between this "frame" and page number but not from the chapter name last word.

Comment: And one more. I don't want hyphenation for the chapter name. I use this code to achieve this: "\setrmarg{2.55em plus1fil}". But when this hack is implemented, hyphenation may appear again.

Comment: Explanation: [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VenM63mHQ-l8Rl54VKaZugWYPqNTr8c1/view?usp=sharing)